# How to get turn by turn or destination from google maps app?

Tags: android, google-maps

How do apps such as 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.headupnav.demo
get turn and destination info?

I want the user to use google maps app, and for my app to run in the background but know distance to the next turn, and where the final destination is.

Others do it, but I cannot understand how they are using the api (or which one)
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/api-picker
 to accomplish the same task?

Please Advise

Answer (score 2):

As far as Google Direction API goes, it is a breach of privacy policies to develop these sort of apps.

As per the documentation goes:

**No navigation. You will not use the Service or Content for or in connection with (a) real-time navigation or route guidance; or (b) automatic or autonomous vehicle control.**

Also Google does not provide any sort of open source API for developers to build turn by turn navigation. The app developers might have designed there own navigation system which is not coming out well as far as the reviews goes.